# $F=ma$ if $ a < 0$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, acceleration, coordinate-systems

The equation $F= m\cdot a$ is known, but what if $a < 0$? Is the force exerted negative?

Comment: Force and acceleration are vector quantities, they have magnitude *and* direction, what does it mean to take the negative of a vector?

Comment: The components (x, y) become (-x, -y) I believe

Comment: That's right. Since the answer has already been given I'll just tell you where I was going, if you take the negative of a vector you end up with a vector pointing in the opposite direction. If the original vector pointed in the direction of your force, or in the direction in which your object is accelerating, the negative of that vector just corresponds to a force in the opposite direction, or an object accelerating in the opposite direction.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, since force is a vector quantity you can have a negative force - simply meaning a force acting in the opposite direction to whatever you have defined as positive.

Comment: Thank you very much